# Browser loses history after a redirect via varnish is sent

Tags: redirect, varnish

I am currently implementing a paywall within varnish. Under certain circumstances I am sending a redirect through varnish:

```
sub process_request {
    if (req.http.count ~ "5") {
        error 302;
    }
}
```

In the corresponding error sub routine I am redirecting like this:

```
sub paywall_redirect {
    if (obj.status == 302 && req.http.count ~ "5") {
        set obj.http.Location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
}
```

Fortunately the logic works, but i am unfortunately loosing browser history for the domain that was used before being redirected to google.com.

Let's say I created a new tab, opened `www.paid-content.com/article.html` for a certain article I want to read and exceed the counter limit (e.g. by reloading the page). Then I get redirected to `www.google.com` and the browser back button is disabled.

Assuming I am coming from `www.website.com` to `www.paid-content.com/article.html` and exceed the limit then the back button brings me back to `www.website.com`.

Is this behavior intended like this? How should I redirect within varnish to keep the browser's history?

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed intended behavior. In essence you are telling the browser that `www.paid-content.com/article.html` is now located at `www.google.com`. The browser caches this information and it also affects the history.

The best way of accomplishing the redirect would be through a custom error handler.

```
sub process_request {
    if (req.http.count ~ "5") {
        error 750;
    }
}
```

Then in your custom error handler create a synthetic response body with a meta refresh tag. Even meta refresh has it's drawbacks, but it should retain browsing history the way you want.

```
sub paywall_redirect {
    if (obj.status == 750 && req.http.count ~ "5") {
        set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
        synthetic {"
           <html>
             <head>
               <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://www.google.com/'">
             </head>
             <body></body>
           </html>
        "};
        return(deliver);
    }
}
```

Perhaps a more elegant solution would be displaying a synthetic page explaining that a paywall has been hit, but that's really a matter of preference.